# Launch script on multiple hosts at same time

Tags: linux

So here is what i want to do. I have a perlScript.pl and a list of machines: machineA,machineB,machineC. These are linux machines that i can ssh into. I want to issue this script on all 3 of these machines at the same time. I am trying to do some load analysis and need to measure the time it takes for the scripts to execute.

Any tips?

Comment: One thing to consider is how closely in time the scripts need to run. If you can be off by a second or two, then even three `ssh user@host command` could do you. If you need millisecond timing, you need to use something to sync the clocks.

Answer (score 4):

you cand find different ssh clients on the net which connect to multiple clients at the same time, so you can execute commands at the same time. one of these clients is [cluster ssh](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/clusterssh/index.php?title=Main_Page). you could give it a try or search for an other client on the net.

Answer (score 1):

Set up NTP so all three boxes are synchronized to a common source.

Then use the [`at` command](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/at.1.php) to run your script (here's a [tutorial](http://www.brunolinux.com/02-The_Terminal/The_at_Command.html))

Comment: I would use `at` instead of `cron`, since the OP probably only wants to trigger the scripts on demand rather than periodically.

Comment: +1 for skipping the ssh part. (If checking for ssh connectivity is not part of the task.)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [dsh](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/dsh.html.en) (distributed shell).

Answer (score 1):

`pssh` is a lot like `dssh`

You get these..

```
/usr/bin/parallel-slurp
/usr/bin/parallel-ssh
/usr/bin/parallel-scp
/usr/bin/parallel-rsync
/usr/bin/parallel-nuke
```

Both `pssh` and `dssh` won't start your jobs at /EXACTLY/ the same time.  The other posters info about at will help you synchronize if you're worried about sub-second variation.

However, I bet your measurements are for longer running jobs that won't mind the slight interval it takes to fork new ssh connections to each host.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone heard about puppet?? iff all the client are open system then puppet will help you a lot. Look at redectivelab website for details.

With that tool you can manage actually hell lot of things. We use it to maintain plethora of servers for the same kind of configuration.

Cheers!

Comment: This sort of thing is not really what puppet is used for.

Comment: yup, as Justin pointed out puppet would be a overkill for this sort of minimal task. Thanks justin

Answer (score 0):

I think people are over-complicating this question.

three machines?  Just ssh into each of them and run

```
time ./perlScript.pl
```

If you have 20,50,100 machines, then sure, use dsh,pssh,cluster-ssh/terminator/whatever.. but 3? just copy the command, open 3 windows, and hit paste 3 times.

I doubt the load analysis needs the commands to be started within milliseconds of each other, what is more useful is timing the actual execution.